# Getting ConcurrentModificationException when I got no extra thread running

Tags: java, multithreading

The following method works if I declare the Iterator inside the method. If I declare it outside the method, it causes a ConcurrentModificationException. I do not have any other thread running for any concurrent operations. I don't get why the difference between declaring it inside and outside the method. I could get away with declaring the iterator in every method but feel that is not efficient. Please advice what is wrong. Thanks.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Linker {

    private static LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        load("sample.txt");
        find("Sam");
    }

    public static void load(String sourceName){
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(sourceName));
            while (in.hasNextLine()){
                String name = in.nextLine();
                list.add(new String(name));
            }
            in.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
    }

    //static ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator(); //causes ConcurrentModificationException
    public static int find(String name){
        ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();//this works
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            String x = iterator.next();
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how about your `theDirect` list?

Comment: Just for testing theDirect is a list of name and numbers: Sam
1234
Daniel
3456
Clark
7890
Alan A
07555

Comment: This is not what I'm talking about; do you modify `theDirect` between calls to `.finder()`?

Comment: No modifications. Just searching through the list.

Comment: -ve voter care to explain why you voted as a negative?

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe you; look at the javadoc of `ConcurrentModificationException`. You _have_ to modify that list somewhere

Comment: I don't see why I should be lying since that is not going to lead me to an answer. The list remains unchanged.

Comment: @kesh_k unless you show more code (hell even the which implementation of List you are using) there isn't enough information at this point to determine what is wrong.  I have to side with fge on this, I would be very surprised if it's not being modified.

Comment: I have re-edited the codes and believe this shows exactly what is going on. Same error where if I declare inside a method, it is fine and declaring it globally, it returns an error. I have commented those lines.

Comment: @kesh_k Take a look at my answer. fge is correct, though you misunderstood his point.  Adding into a list after a ListIterator's creation, can trigger that ListIterator to throw an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists in Java work on a mod count.  That is, before letting anyone use the ListIterator, store the modcount at the moment of creation.  Then when iterating check to see if the modcount at the moment of creation is greater than current modcount.

What you are doing, is creating a ListIterator prior to population of the list setting the List's current modcount to 0.

```
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
private ListIterator<String> itr = list.listIterator(); //at this point mod count is 0

public static void load(String sourceName){
        list.add("Foo");// increment mod count by 1
}
```

So any modifications after load, will increase the modcount by 1.  And since the modcount was 0 prior to creating the ListIterator, any iterator invocation will throw a comodification.

An alternative solution is to create the ListIterator after the load method is finished adding. At that point the modcount will not change.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I'll stick to declaring the iterator inside the method since that ensures the declaration happens after the load method is finished.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may occur when the `theDirect` list is modified between two calls to this method.

When the iterator is obtained in the method, then you will use a "fresh" iterator each time the method is called.

When the iterator is obtained outside of the method, then (during the second call, after someone else has modified the list) it will only notice "Hey, someone else did something with this list, and I can't be sure that I'm in a consistent state any more", and bail out with the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: So is there a way around this such that I can declare it outside of the method and not get caught up with the exception?

Comment: @kesh_k Maybe you should explain what you intend to achieve, or why you think that declaring it in the method is a problem. The only reason I could imagine is that you are adding elements to the end of the list in another method, and in the `finder` method, you try to continue the search from the point where it ended last time. IF this is the case, then you might consider using a list with random access (ArrayList) and instead of storing the iterator, you could store the index where the search ended. But this would not work if you remove elements from the beginning of the list.

Comment: I am using the iterator in another 4 methods. Thus wanted to go for one global declaration instead of making 4 separate declarations.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator should be used as shortly as possible. So it makes absolute sense to create it in the method and nowhere else.

Having created it as an instance field, however, really does not make sense. I assume you add and remove values in other methods. Each time you do, you modify the list, thus the next access to the iterator will throw the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: You mean to say I should not be using an iterator via ListIterator<Direct> it = theDirect.listIterator();?

Comment: Where did I say so? I said, it makes sense to _only_ create it inside a method for the single purpose of that method. So, what I said is, you shall create it, but not as an instance field.

Answer (score 0):

As @Marco13 indicated, the problem is that `theDirect` is being modified between calls to the method. The documentation on most collections is similar to that on [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.

That means that the list itself must not be mutated once an iterator is created (other than through the iterator's methods).